# Track multiple, overlapping website domains with Piwik

Tags: analytics, web-analytics, matomo, web-analytics-tools

I have a dynamic website that I'm integrating with Piwik for analytics.

The website will allow users to have a public 'profile' page and several sub pages related to it. I want to use Piwik to record analytics for the entire website, and to record analytics for each user's profile pages. I want to share the analytics for each profile page with the users.

I'm wondering if I should register a new site_id with piwik when a new user creates a profile and use piwik to track it. Is this possible? Can a site_id in piwik be a standalone site and also part of another website?

for example:
www.example.com <-- entire site
www.example.com/profiles/mike1 <--- site_id 2?
www.example.com/profiles/john1 <--- site_id 3?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Creating a different website in Piwik, for each page that you are tracking, will allow you to easily give access to your users to the statistics of each page. It means you will have 2 tracking codes on these pages (the global piwik code, and the piwik code specific to this page) but this is the best way to give access to your users to their page statistics.

Comment: thanks I've been using this suggestion and it works perfectly!